# Does .NET CLR 4 Exception handling have a performance impact on threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, parallel-processing, clr

I vaguely recall from CLR 2 (and I very well could be wrong) that in a multi-threaded scenario if an exception occurs on one thread the runtime has to temporarily pause the other threads ("pause" might not be accurate).  I think this was related to unwinding the stack.

My question is: "in CLR 4, if an exception occurs and is handled on one of several running threads does it directly impact the performance of the other threads?"

Comment: I would want to know this, too (just out of curiosity) but I doubt the answer will actually buy you anything in practice. If you have constantly recurring exceptions on one thread you either need to fix your code or you're dealing with an external party that keeps blowing up and is out of your control. In this latter case, it doesn't matter what the runtime does because the exceptions will keep coming anyway and your system will take whatever hit that means. If you only have the occasional exception, it won't make much of a difference in the long run.

Comment: Even for the 2.0 CLR that would've been an incredibly stupid implementation. Figuring out the stack trace of one thread shouldn't require touching any other thread. Seems weird.

Comment: @xxbbcc (a prior notice: not having straight the very C# domain expertise, but a need to rigorously test hypotheses to { PASS | FAIL } is universal, isn't it? The more in distributed-systems or parallel-processing ... ) -- **Would that make sense to test it?** By a testing injector-buoy, implemented as a simple "inline"-ed piece of { code | assembly }, that is sure to ad-hoc create such a situation that the system has to throw an exception for the injected-thread-under-test?

Comment: @Voo like I side I might be entirely wrong, after mulling it over this morning I realized I might be mixing it up with CLR 4 GC enhancements, since CLR 2 blocked during GC

Comment: @xxbbcc I agree, I'm actually asking to encourage cleaning up a lot of "normal" exceptions.  Exception handling is certainly expensive on the thread that has to do it, and keeping exceptions for "exceptional/unexpected" circumstances is definitely best

Comment: @STW Oh, you don't even need this to convince people of cleaning up "normal" exceptions - walking the stack is _expensive_ on just a single thread anyway, regardless if it interrupts other threads or no. (I don't think it does but that's unimportant.)

Comment: @STW Seems much more likely. While the CLR 4 GC still stops all threads at some time (there are very few GCs that manage without any stop the world phase - Java has some in specific high performance implementations), it does so for less time. And while throwing exceptions for non-exceptional situations the cost is hardly insurmountable (you generally have to do a table lookup of the IP and if no handler is found, pop the stack [which you'd have to do anyhow if the function returned normally] and then repeat)

Comment: @Voo: Just to be pedantic, the CLR uses a two phase exception handling system, it won't unwind any frames until it has found the catch block that will handle the exception.